# How do I successfully implement my .h file to my main .cpp file to make it run without errors

Tags: c++, class

The code is supposed to take the class from the .h file and use it in the main to create a custom pet synopsis that can be stored later in another text file. I haven't made the modular extraction to a text file yet because I need to get it at least working and able to actually compile and return the different arrays that make up the custom pet synopsis.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
program3.cpp:(.text+0x411): undefined reference to `dog_list::dog_list()'
/usr/bin/ld: program3.cpp:(.text+0x426): undefined reference to `dog_list::~dog_list()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My .h file

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cctype>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 20;
const int END = 11;
class dog_list
{
    public:
    dog_list();
    ~dog_list();
    void record_pets();
    private:
    char name[SIZE];
    char breed[SIZE];
    char species[SIZE];
    char service[SIZE];
    char special[SIZE];
};
dog_list op;


void record_pets();
```

---

my main .cpp file

```
#include "program3.h"
int main()
{
       op.record_pets();
        return 0;

}


void dog_list::record_pets()
{
    char personal_list[SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    char again;

    do
    {

        cout << "Enter in pets name: ";
        cin.get(op.name,25,'\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');   
        cout << endl << "Enter breed of pet:  ";
        cin.get(op.breed, 25, '\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl << "Enter species: ";
        cin.get(op.species,25,'\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl <<  "Enter in service qualifications: ";
        cin.get(op.service,25,'\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl << "Enter in special notes: ";
        cin.get(op.special,25,'\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Name:  " << op.name << endl;
        cout <<"Breed: " <<  op.breed << endl;
        cout << "Species: " << op.species << endl;
        cout << "Service Qualifications: " << op.service << endl;
        cout << "Special Notes: " << op.special << endl;

        cout << "Pet saved! Would you like to enter another pet? Y/N: " << endl;
        cin >> again;
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl;

        if(again == 'y')
        {
            again = toupper(again);
        }


    }while(again == 'Y' && i <= END);
    {
        ++i;    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your header file *declares* a constructor for `dog_list()` but does not *define* (i.e. implement it).   The message you get is from the linker, and reports it cannot find the definition of that constructor.   So, you need to implement the constructor.   There are other problems in your code as well, but that's the one you asked about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never implement the constructor and destructor, you just declare it:

```cpp
dog_list();
~dog_list();
```

You have to implement it, for example, in main.cpp:

```cpp
dog_list::dog_list() = default;
dog_list::~dog_list() = default;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I did as you said and it now gives me regular errors however now I'm receiving these errors and im not sure how to fix them.
program3.cpp:4:21: error: cannot call constructor ‘dog_list::dog_list’ directly [-fpermissive]
4 |dog_list::dog_list() = default;
program3.cpp:4:21: note: for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::dog_list’
program3.cpp:4:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘default’
    4 |dog_list::dog_list() = default;
program3.cpp:5:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘dog_list::~dog_list()’
    5 |dog_list::~dog_list() = default;

Comment: You're probably using a pre-C++11 compiler.   Before C++11, the `=default`  constructs were not part of standard C++.