# How do I successfully implement my .h file to my main .cpp file to make it run without errors, examp,es would be very helpful thank you

Tags: c++, class, constructor

The code is supposed to take the class from the .h file and use it in the main to create a custom pet synopsis that can be stored later in another text file. I haven't made the modular extraction to a text file yet because I need to get it at least working and able to actually compile and return the different arrays that make up the custom pet synopsis.

whenever i run the code it reads the following errors:

```
program3.cpp:5:21: error: cannot call constructor ‘dog_list::dog_list’ directly                                                                                                                                                              [-fpermissive]
    5 |  dog_list::dog_list() = default;
      |                     ^
program3.cpp:5:21: note: for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::dog_                                                                                                                                                             list’
program3.cpp:5:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘default’
    5 |  dog_list::dog_list() = default;
      |                         ^~~~~~~
program3.cpp:6:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘dog_list::~dog_list(                                                                                                                                                             )’
    6 |  dog_list::~dog_list() = default;
      |                      ^
program3.h:12:2: note: candidate: ‘dog_list::~dog_list()’
   12 |  ~dog_list();
      |  ^
program3.h:12:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
program3.cpp:6:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘default’
    6 |  dog_list::~dog_list() = default;
      |                          ^~~~~~~
```

my .h file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cctype>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 20;
const int END = 11;
class dog_list
{
    public:
    dog_list();
    ~dog_list();
    void record_pets();
    private:
    char name[SIZE];
    char breed[SIZE];
    char species[SIZE];
    char service[SIZE];
    char special[SIZE];
};
void record_pets();
```

my main .cpp file:

```
#include "program3.h"
int main()
{
       op.record_pets();
        return 0;

}


void dog_list::record_pets()
{
    char personal_list[SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    char again;

    do
    {

        cout << "Enter in pets name: ";
        cin.get(op.name,25,'\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');   
        cout << endl << "Enter breed of pet:  ";
        cin.get(op.breed, 25, '\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl << "Enter species: ";
        cin.get(op.species,25,'\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl <<  "Enter in service qualifications: ";
        cin.get(op.service,25,'\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl << "Enter in special notes: ";
        cin.get(op.special,25,'\n');
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Name:  " << op.name << endl;
        cout <<"Breed: " <<  op.breed << endl;
        cout << "Species: " << op.species << endl;
        cout << "Service Qualifications: " << op.service << endl;
        cout << "Special Notes: " << op.special << endl;

        cout << "Pet saved! Would you like to enter another pet? Y/N: " << endl;
        cin >> again;
        cin.ignore(100,'\n');
        cout << endl;

        if(again == 'y')
        {
            again = toupper(again);
        }


    }while(again == 'Y' && i <= END);
    {
        ++i;    
    }   
}
```

Comment: hi holly, i just was curious as to where you added that

Comment: (kind of) similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960187/how-do-i-successfully-implement-my-h-file-to-my-main-cpp-file-to-make-it-run-w/

Comment: Nevermind, I tested the code incorrectly. :/ There is at least one more .cpp file you're not showing us.

Answer (score 2):

You declare a constructor and destructor, but you didn't implement those functions as you did the `record_pets` member function.  Also, you forgot to declare what type `op` is in main

You don't need a destructor - since there's nothing to cleanup that isn't handled for you. But you likely do need a constructor implementation.

You declare your array sizes to be `SIZE=20`, but you read up to 25 chars in your `cin` statements.  So let's fix that.  Instead of statements like:

```
cin.get(op.service,25,'\n');
```

Say this:

```
cin.get(op.service,dog_list::SIZE,'\n');
```

Everything else I have below is mainly just code cleanup.

program3.h as follows:

```
#pragma once

class dog_list
{
public:
    static const int SIZE = 25;
    dog_list();
    void record_pets();
private:
    char name[SIZE];
    char breed[SIZE];
    char species[SIZE];
    char service[SIZE];
    char special[SIZE];
};
```

main.cpp as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cctype>
#include<fstream>
#include "program3.h"

using namespace std;
const int END = 11;


dog_list::dog_list() :
    name(),  // zero-init each array member
    breed(),
    species(),
    service(),
    special()
{
}


void dog_list::record_pets()
{

    // all that code you have in your implementation above
}

int main()
{
    dog_list op;
    op.record_pets();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hello selbie, thank you for such a good answer, the issue im having now is that i made all the changes however im now getting this error: program3.cpp: In member function ‘void dog_list::record_pets()’:
program3.cpp:23:11: error: ‘op’ was not declared in this scope
   23 |   cin.get(op.name,dog_list::SIZE,'\n');
      |                 ^~

Comment: Instead of `cin.get(op.service,dog_list::SIZE,'\n');`,  say `cin.get(service,dog_list::SIZE,'\n');`  Repeat for all the other offending lines.

Comment: Thank you i think i almost got it working, I am now getting the error program3test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
program3test.cpp:23:2: error: ‘record_pets’ was not declared in this scope
   23 |  record_pets();
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: im also confused as to what the purpose of the below code you suggested:    
  dog_list::dog_list():
        name(),  // zero-init each array member
        breed(),
        species(),
        service(),
        special()

Comment: That's called a constructor initializer list.  By specifying `breed()` and similar declarations it zero-inits your array variable so it doesn't have garbage in it.